# android strange background of ExpandableListView's child

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I have ExpandableListView with one group and one child.
When I expand group the child looks as I want. See:
[image: good child]

But when I tap on child and move my finger to up of the screen (it is no matter how far - 10 px or 50 px) and remove my finger I see this white backgroud:
[image: bad child]

How can I avoid this behavior?

EDITED 1:
I tried one more time and discovered that background changed even if I still pressing on screen. It happens where my finger is above the group view.

EDITED 2:

```
<ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/list_filters"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:groupIndicator="@null" 
        android:divider="@null"/>
```

Comment: Do you see it as it is scrolling or when it stops?

Comment: @mango If I understood you question correct - when it stops (when I remove my finger from screen)

Comment: @mango I tried one more time and discovered that background changed even if I still pressing on screen. It happens where my finger is above the group view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would appear to be the cache color hint...  If you set it to transparent I believe your issue will be solved.

You can do that in code with `yourlistView.setCacheColorHint(0)` or in the XML with `android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"`.

Answer (score 0):

This might be because of the background color. Try setting the selector as background to child views. The selector should have the entries state_pressed and state_selected.

Comment: can you add expandable list view xml code..? I will also try.

Comment: Please try to set the background to ExpandableListView. It should work..!!